# unable to deploy Android APK on a blackberry device

Tags: blackberry-10, android-install-apk

I have been trying to figure this out for a couple of days now,
I created some apps, I followed the steps to get a signed APK (https://www.udacity.com/wiki/ud853/course_resources/creating-a-signed-apk) .
The APK installs fine on android devices, but when I try to deploy on BB device, I get a "unable to install" message. An APK (downloaded from google play to my PC, then saved to the BB device) installs fine on the BB device, but non of my apps can be installed. 
I think I am missing something I should do before or after creating the signed APK. Is there a way to diagnose or find the reason the installation is failing??

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.asamater.myapplication" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

minimum supported API must be 18 or under.